# Renewenvironment minipage with xparse

Tags: minipage, xparse

I want to redefine the minipage environment which has several optional parameters. The default `renewenvironment` allows only a single optional argument. Therefore, I try to use the [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse?lang=en) package which offers `\RenewDocumentEnvironment`:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{minipage}{O{} O{} O{} m}{\begin{minipage}[#1][#2][#3]{#4}}{\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  hello world
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

However, this document does not compile successfully:

```
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
 \__xparse_grab_arg:w ...e_args_tl }}\group_begin: 
                                                   \token_if_eq_catcode:NNTF ...
 l.5 \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}

 !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
 Transcript written on demo-xparse-minipage.log.
```

Comment: You have to `\let\originalminipage\minipage` and `\let\originalendminipage\endminipage` and then `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{minipage}{..}{\originalminipage[#1][#2][#3]{#4}}{\originalendminipage}`.

Comment: Thanks. It successfully compiles now. However, my MWE creates an empty minipage. Do you see what is wrong? Currently, the output should be the same (with or without renewenvironemnt). I have not added my modifications.

Comment: Apparently, I have to take care for different numbers of arguments. Answer by egreg shows how it can be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't redefine `minipage` in terms of itself; you have also to parse carefully the optional arguments, as LaTeX cannot comply with empty optional arguments to the original `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

% save the old commands
\let\latexminipage\minipage
\let\latexendminipage\endminipage

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{minipage}{ooom}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\latexminipage{#4}}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\latexminipage[#1]{#4}}
     {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}
       {\latexminipage[#1][#2]{#4}}
       {\latexminipage[#1][#2][#3]{#4}}%
     }%
   }%
 }
 {\latexendminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
  hello world
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{3cm}
  hello world\\
  hello world
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b][4cm]{3cm}
  hello world\\
  hello world
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b][4cm][s]{3cm}
  hello world

  \vfill

  hello world
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know you don't like these kind of comments, but this time I don't mind... My congratulations for yours 400k reputation and my best wishes for the next step: 1/2 million! Grande Enrico. And thanks for all the knowledge you share with us in the site!

Comment: @karlkoeller: `♥`

Comment: Wouldn't using `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let` be better because it does not need the fiddling with optional arguments?

Comment: @stefanct `\minipage` doesn't have an optional argument in its current implemetation. It is defined with `\@ifnextchar`.